# Asynctask go wrong when executing so many times

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I want to make a progress bar like [Timberman game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cqgzk_opMCQ). 
This is my Java code:

```
boolean flagProgress=false;
private void click() {// click 1 button
    if(!flagProgress){
        taskProgress=new TaskProgress();
        AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(taskProgress,
                500+10); 
    }
    else {
        taskProgress.cancel(true);
        int progress=progressBar.getProgress();
        taskProgress=new TaskProgress();
        AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel(taskProgress,
                progress+10);
    }
}  

class TaskProgress extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
        super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        doGameOver();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        flagProgress=true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        progressBar.setProgress(values[0]);            
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        if(params[0]>1000)// max 1000
            params[0]=1000;
        setProgress(params[0]);

        for(int i=params[0];i>=0;i--) {

            if(isCancelled())
                break;
            publishProgress(i);
            SystemClock.sleep(100);
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        super.onCancelled();
    }
}
```

Everything went right(my Progress bar looked like Progress bar in Timberman game) until I played my game 20 times or more (game over and play again). My progress bar stopped and sometimes sound effect didn't play. Note: I also have an other AsyncTask so I use AsyncTaskCompat.executeParallel.
Who can help me? :(.